# How to configure schema.xml for geoSpatial Search in solr

Tags: java, kotlin, solr, sap-commerce-cloud, solrcloud

I want to filter data nearby location using Solr Spatial Search but can't find any data

I want to filter data nearby location using Solr Spatial Search but can't find any data.

I have done the following changes in schema.xml:

```
<fieldType name="location" class="solr.LatLonPointSpatialField" docValues="true" />
<field name="latlong" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="false"/> 
<field name="location" type="location" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
```

Query :

q=*:*&fq={!geofilt%20sfield=location}&pt=22.303894,70.802162&d=5

Response :

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "zkConnected":true,
    "status":0,
    "QTime":0,
    "params":{
      "q":"*:*",
      "pt":"22.303894,70.802162",
      "d":"5",
      "fq":"{!geofilt sfield=location}"}},
  "response":{"numFound":0,"start":0,"numFoundExact":true,"docs":[]
  }}
```

Expected Document:

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "zkConnected":true,
    "status":0,
    "QTime":0,
    "params":{
      "q":"*:*",
      "indent":"true",
      "q.op":"OR",
      "_":"1671173790419"}},
  "response":{"numFound":1,"start":0,"numFoundExact":true,"docs":[
      {
        "brandnd_name":["Luxury"],  
        "country":["India"],
        "latitude":[22.2913494],
        "longitude":[70.8023621],
        "updated_date":["54:03.6"],
        "added_date":["0018-05-14T11:19:00Z"],
        "active_ind":[true],
        "synxis_hotel_id":[37273],
        "id":"4598a178-d984-41f1-b009-bbda37469b7c",
        "_version_":1752351636887437312},
```

Comment: Is there any `location` field in your document? You haven't included that in the response, so it's hard to tell whether you've added any field named `location` (which you're filtering against).

Comment: no i just mapped latlong to that location field

Comment: Where did you add that mapping? There doesn't seem to be any content in a field named `location`, so if you're not getting the information added properly, there won't be any search results..

Comment: <fieldType name="location" class="solr.LatLonPointSpatialField" docValues="true"/>
 
<field name="latlong" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="false"/> 
<field name="location" type="location" indexed="true" stored="true"  ="false"/>
<copyField source="latlong"  dest="location"/>

Comment: this is how I configured is there any changes that i wanna do ?

Comment: in schem.xml file

Comment: Are you sending any content for the `latlong` field, then? Switch it to stored while debugging to see what kind of content you're submitting for the field as well; you also have to make sure that you reload the core after changing the schema.